# Python "InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type."

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas

When I run the following code, I keep getting the "InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type" error, and I need help identifying where the problem is. Everything works fine up until I try to send the data to sql through.

```
anagramsdf.to_sql('anagrams',con=conn,if_exists='replace',index=False)
cdf=pd.read_sql("select (distinct ID) from anagrams;",conn)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("anagrams")
xsorted=sorted(anagrams,key=sorted)
xunique=[x[0] for x in anagrams]

xunique=pd.Series(xunique)
xanagrams=pd.Series(anagrams)
anagramsdf=pd.concat([xunique,dfcount,xanagrams],axis=1)
anagramsdf.columns=['ID','anagram_count','anagram_list']

c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("create table anagrams(ID, anagram_count, anagram_list)")
conn.commit()

anagramsdf.to_sql('anagrams',con=conn,if_exists='replace',index=False)
cdf=pd.read_sql("select (distinct ID) from anagrams;",conn)

cdf=pd.read_sql("select max(anagram_count) from anagrams;",conn)
cdf
def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')

cdf=pd.read_sql("select * from anagrams where anagram_count=12;",conn)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',200)
```

Full traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlpandas.py", line 88, in <module>
    anagramsdf.to_sql('anagrams',con=conn,if_exists='replace',index=False)
  File "/Users/andrewclark/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 982, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/andrewclark/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 549, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/andrewclark/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1567, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "/Users/andrewclark/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 728, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/Users/andrewclark/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1357, in _execute_insert
    conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Snippet from Dataframe:

```
             ID  anagram_count           anagram_list
0            aa              1                  (aa,)
1      anabaena              1            (anabaena,)
2      baaskaap              1            (baaskaap,)
3      caracara              1            (caracara,)
4      caragana              1            (caragana,)
```

Comment: Can you reduce the example to a couple of lines? All the code with `urllib`,  `itertools`, `print` statements, etc., doesn't add anything useful. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, depending upon which line the error is raised, this could be an issue with [tag:pandas], and the question needs appropriate tagging.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: Can you show `anagramsdf.info()`? Or ideally, make a reproducible example to make up the dataframe.

Comment: The `anagram_list` column contains tuples, which is not supported by sqlite to insert in a dataframe. Therefore converting it to strings solves the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code to change the datatypes to strings, and this solved the problem:

```
anagramsdf.dtypes
anagramsdf['ID']= anagramsdf['ID'].astype('str')
anagramsdf['anagram_list']= anagramsdf['anagram_list'].astype('str')
anagramsdf.to_sql('anagramsdf',con=conn,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Comment: The `anagram_list` column contains tuples, which is not supported by sqlite to insert in a dataframe. Therefore converting it to strings solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation joris!

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas 0.23.4 I have a column with datetime values (format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') that is of data type "string" that was throwing the same error when I tried to pass it to "to_sql" method. After converting to "datetime" dtype it worked. Hope that's helpful to someone with the same issue :).

To convert:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format=datetimeFormat,errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sparrow's solution worked for me. If the index is not converted to a datetime then SQL is going to throw "error binding parameter"

I used a column that had the datetimes to first convert to the correct format and then use it as the index:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']), inplace=True)
```